# Blender freezes when infinite loop is used

Tags: python, ubuntu, blender

I am using a client server architechture, and the client side is on the blender.

Since, client has to infinitely wait for the text from server, I have used an infinite while loop. But, Blender freezes the moment I run the script, it doesn't show anything happening in each step, and when I end the execution manually using command line, it just shows the last step executed.

The script works perfectly if run outside blender. I am using Blender 2.74 on ubuntu.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you provide your actual code, please? We prefer to provide answers, not speculation.

Comment: @Zenohm: Or somebody who knows these innards of Blender shows up and knows this problem and what causes it. This problem is easy to understand without the code. It's a simply matter of main-loop stalling. In fact, having the Python code would not help in the slightest, because it doesn't show the full picture (the Python interpreter built into Blender) and you have to know how Python integrated into Blender to see where the problem is. But if you know about the later, then just reading a few keywords is enough.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you're running into is a standard issue with **every** event based, interactive application: Input events and displaying their response happens in a application main event loop, where the gist is about

```
while(running) {
    event = poll_event()
    if( event ) {
        dispatch_event(event)
    }
    redraw_window()
}
```

Now when you execute a script in Blender, this happens somewhere "within" the `dispatch_event()` call chain in response to some event, for example you clicking a UI button or hitting the run script hotkey, or by simply a Blender executing your script because it's been registered as a hook to something.

At long as your loop is running, down in `dispatch_event()`, the execution of the main application loop is stalled, freezing the rest of the program.

So what can you do about this: Either don't implement such an inner server loop in your program, but use the framework's method to register a new event and piggyback on the existing event loop (in Blender this is called a "***modal*** *operator*". Or, in your case probably the preferred thing, create a thread for your server to run in concurrently to the main event loop.

Also see https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_76_1/info_gotcha.html#can-i-redraw-during-the-script which is relevent in your case.